# What are difference between a data, a Statistic and a Value?

Tags: terminology, definition

A data (datum?) is an information such as

"**tree 1 has a height of 5 meter**" it is a data. Up to best of my understanding, height is a variable and 5 meter is a value. A variable and an associated value making up a data (datum?).

A statistic is any quantity computed from values in a sample that is used for a statistical purpose.

Such as

> "The manager of a large hotel located near Disney World indicated that 20 selected guests had a **mean length of stay equal to 5.6 days**."
> In this example, "5.6 days" is a statistic, namely the mean length of stay for our sample of 20 hotel guests. The population is the set of all guests of this hotel, and the parameter is the mean length of stay for all guests - ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistic))

It looks like same as a datum. Also the quotation mark around "5.6 days" makes me think whether the term statistic means value.

*Now my question is what are the differences between data, statistic and value.*

**What I have already tried:** I have consulted my textbok 'Introduction to Biostatistics (A textbook of biometry)' by Dr. P. K. Banerjee; Also I have visited various website on google. However the differences are not clearing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think "values" has a precise definition, but here is my attempt.

A datum is a single piece of data.  The datum can be comprised of many values.  For example, if you seek to collect height, weight, and age measurements from people, then a datum would be a single observation of someone's height, weight, and age.  Data are thus several observations of these values.

A statistic is a function of data.  Take the sample mean for example.  We input the data into this function and are returned a single value (or multiple values were you to compute the sample mean of a vector, for example).

Comment: So may I call a statistic is basically same as a "secondary data"?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused no. Statistics are not data in themselves. The are functions of data.

Comment: Note that this answer does not differentiate sample statistic/population parameter.